# ajax post not being sent when 'change' event is triggered in jquery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery, ajax, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

I've snipped out parts of code for readability. The positions function below is executed when the change event is triggered by dragging on a child element of col_1:

```
$('#col_1').Sortable(
                    {
                        change:  positions,
                    }
                );
```

The problem is 'positions' sends an ajax post to the server which isn't going through:

```
function positions(){

   **i've removed some javascript code leading to a javascript variable called "variable" ***

xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
xmlhttp.open('POST', '/positions.php', true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("epositions="+variable);
xmlhttp.send(null);


    return true;
}
```

So the Post isn't sent to the server. But I have noticed that if I instead put

```
  $('#col_1').Sortable(
                    {
                            change: function() { positions(); },
                    }
                );
```

The ajax post gets sent when the handle of a childnode in col_1 is clicked on, but the elements can no longer be sorted. Having

```
   change: function(data) { positions(); },
```

does not send the ajax request either, although the elements are sorted.

How do I overcome this problem? Am I doing something wrong or is it a problem with UI sortable?

Answer (score 0):

I put a script that might help you.  It is a complete example, click here:
[XML POST EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167340/ajax-jquery-variables-not-passing-to-php)

(E.g. Search for **test.php** )

Comment: Hi Melsi. I am familiar with how to pass ajax calls and have done so in other parts of my website. What causes the problem in the above is the 'change' part of the UI sortable plugin. Unless you are saying the problem is caused by my using actual javascript code rather than jquery in my code above, I'm not sure how what you linked helps.

Comment: For example, positions() successfully makes an ajax post when called by other means, I have tested. It's just when it is called through the 'change' part of jquery ui sortable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I see, I have an other suspicion (sorry if this is not the case).

This suspission is because I don't see where onreadystatechange is in yor code.

As you already know it is the onreadystatechange that will call some function you like and not the other way around.

I don't see why the

```
xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
```

must be inside a function, this will make thing start over and finding your self traveling through states until the 4 state every time you call positions. If you look at my code it is out of the function. How are things sepearetd in my code is a result of hard work and can affect things a lot.

Also check out how and where is used `onreadystatechange` .

That's all what I wanted to mention:

1. Take care of the xml request (you want it called at the very beginnign only once) so being inside a function doesn't look a good idea (even worse if you consider variable scopes!!!!)
2. Take care of the onreadystatechange and other xml http code, you want it in your function so every time it brings fresh results!!!
3. Take care of the states!

I ask for understanding if all this is not the case and the answer is of no help!

As for jquery I don't use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `change` callback require a `return true;` to work?
If so, you can update the code to use `change: function(data) { return positions(); }`