# how to access jquery variable in php

Tags: php, jquery

My question is very very similar to this one 
[How to get jQuery variable value in PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401110/how-to-get-jquery-variable-value-in-php-file)

The difference is I have some code samples. I just cant seem to get a satisfactory answer for what I am looking for. I am doing all these in one php file. Is this even possible?

I want to store categoryChoiceVal into $category

Here is the html

```
<select class="categoryChoice ">
    <option>Gym class</option>
    <option>Math tutorial</option>
    <option>Basketball court</option>
</select>
```

the php

```
<?php

    $category = '';
    $query_string = "https//this_is_a_dummy_string.htm?{$category}";

    $data = file_get_contents($query_string);

?>
```

I am catching the selection from the select tag by doing this

```
$(function(){

    $('select').change(function() {
        var categoryChoiceVal = $('.categoryChoice option:selected').text();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to make an asynchronous request to your PHP script on the server. How to do so is literally all over the internet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=access+jquery+variable+in+php

Comment: The answer is the same as in the other question you referred to: To get a value from javascript/jQuery (client) to PHP (server), you need to send it. Ajax is the choice to do that, unless you want to reload the entire page.

Comment: Hi, it would be very helpful if someone can share some code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX + jQuery... Variables not passing to PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167340/ajax-jquery-variables-not-passing-to-php)

Comment: @Bojangles-- all over the internet is not really helpful...if you have something to share feel free. I know it would have to be an ajax but I am a bit lost with the implementation. Ihavent really worked with php much

Comment: @LuckySoni--it is not really a duplicate...if you read it carefully..i am not accessing a separate php file. How it changes the used case, if you have any comment to that please add that

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$category = '';
if (isset($_POST['categoryChoiceVal'])){
 $category = $_POST['categoryChoiceVal'];
}
$query_string = "https//this_is_a_dummy_string.htm?{$category}";

$data = file_get_contents($query_string);

 ?>

$(function(){

   $('select').change(function() {
       $.post('phpUrl',{
        categoryChoiceVal:$('.categoryChoice option:selected').text()
      });

  });
});
```